# removing collinarity of resulting dummy variable columns

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I am currently reviewing some work which uses 'dummy variable encoding' as described [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/dummyvar.html?requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com):

```
D = dummyvar(group)
D =
     1     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0     1
     1     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1     0
```

In this work collinar columns were removed by removing the densest columns (i.e. the ones containing the most 1s). In the example above this would mean that column 1 or(?) 2 would be removed. I can see no justification for this and would usually measure variance inflation factors or check correlation between independent variables using other methods. Is there any theoretical justification for removing dense columns in a scenario like the one described above?

Comment: 1 and 2 are highly collinear and hence one of them must have been removed. I am yet to come across a justification for removal of a column based on how densely or sparsely it is populated.

Comment: Maybe because it is more dense it is more likely to be correlated? Not sure though. I would not think thats a valid argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using linear regression (or some related method like glm's) (and the model includes an intercept term), then, which dummy variable column you drop to avoid perfect colinearity shouldn't matter. The model defined **do not depend on which column you drop**. (the choice of which column to drop simply corresponds to choice between different bases of the same linear subspace.)

Maybe, if you encounter numerical problems with the fitting, you could experiment to see if dropping some other column helps (probably not.) I would rather look into other remedy's, like regularization.  For a better answer we need some context.